# Burninate the recommendations tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, burninate

[recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) is a tag that exists. Despite it being very, very hard to see any time when a "recommendation" isn't going to be both opinion based and spam. Even the tag wiki kinda says "if you're using this tag, it will probably get closed".

Should we just kill the tag?

Comment: I suggest changing it to "if you use this tag, your question WILL get closed" ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo As "off-topic" too.

Answer (score 4):

[Asking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes:

> soliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place (unless VERY specific criteria is listed)

so some requests for recommendations are permissible. However it is a meta tag and should be burninated. It might be argued that experts on recommendations do exist (maybe on Software Recommendations for example) but "VERY specific criteria" seems to exclude the sort of 'theme' that might justify retention.

The tag only has one follower.

Comment: Errr. When I go to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations I see lots of uses